# MySQL - error when declaring a variable

Tags: mysql

I've written a small code block (which later be used in a event in MySQL but I'm getting an error when declaring a seemingly standard INT variable:

```
BEGIN
      DECLARE myvar INT;
      SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF INTO myvar (MINUTE,(select user_hb_stamp from eclipse_users where username = 'user1'),(SELECT NOW()));

      IF (myvar > 5)
            UPDATE eclipse_users SET logged=0 WHERE username = 'user1';
END
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are perhaps missing the delimiter at the beginning. `delimiter //` so that any `;` are not interpreted as end of code block.

Comment: You mess mysql with ms sql server.

Answer (score 1):

Your `select` statement is malformed.  Try this:

```
  SELECT myvar := TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
                                (select user_hb_stamp from eclipse_users where username = 'user1'),
                                NOW());
```

Although you *can* use `into` for variables, I prefer to just set them directly -- unless you are writing code that needs to be compatible with Oracle.  (And then all the function calls won't work.)

A more typical way to write this is:

```
  SELECT myvar := TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, user_hb_stamp, NOW())
  FROM eclipse_users 
  WHERE username = 'user1';
```

EDIT:

As for the `declare` itself, the problem is probably the lack of `delimiter` statement.  Try:

```
delimiter $$

create procedure . . .
begin
    declare p_myvar int;

    select p_myvar := TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, user_hb_stamp, NOW())
    from eclipse_users 
    where username = 'user1';

    . . .
end$$
delimiter ;
```